# Why does ruby automatically combine Strings?

Tags: ruby, string

If I have this code:

```
a = "hi" "pie"
puts a
```

It will print out `hipie`. Does Ruby automatically combine these?

Comment: See also [Why do two strings separated by space concatenate in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23811203/1422127), [Strange string behavior in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23206687/1422127), and [How String concatenation works in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27763763/1422127).

Comment: Is the question whether it does so or why it does so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. From [Literals: String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)

> Adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the interpreter:
>
> ```
> "con" "cat" "en" "at" "ion" 
> #=> "concatenation"
> "This string contains " "no newlines."              
> #=> "This string contains no newlines."
> ```