# How String concatenation works in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, space

How the following line of code concatenates a string in ruby?

```
2.1.0 :052 > value = "Kamesh" "Waran"
 => "KameshWaran"
```

I understand that '+' is a method on String class which concatenates the strings passed. How the space(' ') can be the operator/method?

Can anyone elaborate how the space(' ') concatenate strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is not an operator.  This only works for string *literals*, and is just part of the literal syntax, like the double-quotes.  If you have two string literals with nothing but whitespace between them, they get turned into a single string.  It's a convention borrowed from later versions of C.

```
irb(main):001:0> foobar = "foo" "bar"
=> "foobar"
irb(main):002:0> foo="foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> bar="bar"
=> "bar"
irb(main):004:0> foo bar
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for main:Object
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a search on this site you get an answer.

Found on : 
[Why do two strings separated by space concatenate in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811203/why-do-two-strings-separated-by-space-concatenate-in-ruby)

> Implementation details can be found in parse.y file in Ruby source
>   code. Specifically, here.
>
> A Ruby string is either a tCHAR (e.g. ?q), a string1 (e.g. "q", 'q',
>   or %q{q}), or a recursive definition of the concatenation of string1
>   and string itself, which results in string expressions like "foo"
>   "bar", 'foo' "bar" or ?f "oo" 'bar' being concatenated.