# Why does not this case expression cause a syntax error?

Tags: ruby, syntax, string-literals

I wrote a case expression like

```rb
case x
when "one" "I"
when "two" "II"
end
```

It does not cause a syntax error, and always returns `nil` regardless of the value of `x`. I think it should cause a syntax error, but the reality is not the case. Why?

Comment: Btw a hash might be faster than a case block in this example...

Comment: Try for `x` being `"oneI"` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white-space separated string literals get concatenated (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811203/why-do-two-strings-separated-by-space-concatenate-in-ruby)).  That turns your `when` statements into legitimate potential matches with no action to be performed, which is why you always get `nil`.