# Odd string concatenation in ruby, feature or bug?

Tags: ruby

We just got stung by an apparent 'feature' in ruby where if you put 2 strings side by side they are automatically concatenated together, i.e.:

```
irb(main):001:0> ['h1', 'h2' 'h3']
=> ["h1", "h2h3"]
```

Why would this not throw an error? It seems surprising.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18193792/438992

Comment: This is documented in the Ruby official [string literal docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)