# Surprising string concatenation

Tags: ruby

I am surprised by some string concatenation I've stumbled upon in a codebase I support.  Why, or how really, does the following manage to concatenate two strings together?

```
queue_name = 'gen-request-' "#{ENV['USERNAME'].gsub('.','')}"
=> "gen-request-robertkuhar"
```

I had expected to see a '+' between the two strings, but its not there.  Is it implied or something?

I know this just makes more sense with up-the-middle string interpolation.  Thats not what I'm asking.  I want to know what it is about the language syntax that allows this to work in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193792/where-is-rubys-string-literal-juxtaposition-feature-officially-documented

Comment: While the answer is the same, I don't think this is a duplicate of the "where is juxtaposition documented" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works for string literals, and a part of the literal syntax.

If you have 2 string literals with just whitespace between them, they get turned into a single string. It's a convention borrowed from later versions of C.

Comment: Oh my.  You learn something new everyday.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193792/where-is-rubys-string-literal-juxtaposition-feature-officially-documented
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work